# Represent ASCII EOH character as string?

Tags: c++, boost, ascii

I'd like to use the code below to split a line based on the ASCII "Start Of Heading" (SOH) character:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
std::vector<std::string> strs;
boost::split(strs, "string to split", boost::is_any_of("\t "));
```

As you can see, the delimiter is represented by the string "\t ". How do I represent the SOH character as a string to split on?

http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Comment: Make it "\t \x1". Read about escape sequences in your favorite C or C++ textbook.

Comment: Use `"\x01"` as the delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can use a hex sequence to represent the character. You can make your code a little more readable by taking advantage of macros to define the character and string literal concatenation to turn multiple strings into a single one:

```
#define SOH "\x01"
#define TAB "\t"

boost::split(strs, "string to split", boost::is_any_of(TAB " " SOH));
```